# getting Gremlin-console error while gremlin console is attempting to connect to arcadedb in docker

Tags: docker, java-8, gremlin, remote-connection, arcadedb

I am trying to use Gremlin query language for access data in ArcadeDB, but I am getting this error.
I've started Gremlin-Console and ArcadeDB in Docker
and trying to connect.
What am I doing wrong?

#### Launch ArcadeDB with Docker:

```js
    docker run --name arcade-db \
                --rm -p 2480:2480 -p 2424:2424 -p 8182:8182 -p 6379:6379 -p 5432:5432 \
               -e JAVA_OPTS="-Darcadedb.server.rootPassword=playwithdata
                              -Darcadedb.server.plugins=GremlinServer:com.arcadedb.server.gremlin.GremlinServerPlugin
                              -Darcadedb.server.defaultDatabases=Imported[root]{import:https://github.com/ArcadeData/arcadedb-datasets/raw/main/orientdb/OpenBeer.gz}"\
               -d arcadedata/arcadedb:22.8.1
```

#### `dockerfile` for gremlin-console:

```yaml
    FROM openjdk:8
    
    ARG tinkerpopVersion
    
    WORKDIR /opt
    RUN wget https://www.apache.org/dist/tinkerpop/$tinkerpopVersion/apache-tinkerpop-gremlin-console-$tinkerpopVersion-bin.zip
    RUN unzip ./apache-tinkerpop-gremlin-console-$tinkerpopVersion-bin.zip
    WORKDIR /opt/apache-tinkerpop-gremlin-console-$tinkerpopVersion
    COPY arcade-db-remote.yaml /opt/apache-tinkerpop-gremlin-console-$tinkerpopVersion
    ENTRYPOINT ["bin/gremlin.sh"]
```

#### Config-file for gremlin-console:

```yaml
    hosts: [localhost]
    port: 8182
    connectionPool: { enableSsl: false }
    serializer: { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphBinaryMessageSerializerV1,
                  config: { serializeResultToString: true  }}
```

#### Error:

```js
    Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
            at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
            at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:716)
            at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:337)
            at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:334)
            at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:776)
            at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724)
            at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650)
            at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562)
            at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
            at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
    ==>Configured localhost/127.0.0.1:8182, but host not presently available. The Gremlin Console will attempt to reconnect on each query submission, however, you may wish to close this remote and investigate the problem directly.
```

Comment: Do you see from the ArcadeDB server logs that the gremlin server runs at startup?

Comment: sure i see it, it is working on arcade db version 23.4.1

Comment: Have you tried the latest version of ArcaedDB?

Comment: Testing on the latest version of arcadedb, the logs say that it failed to load the gremlin server plugin. And trying to connect from a gremlin console does not work.